# Error: unknown element <provider> found

Tags: android, build, camera, manifest

I am trying to follow the tutorial here : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

to make an application using the camera and taking photos. At one point, it is explained that a provider must be provided (ahah) in the manifest to store the picture we took with the camera.

Here is my problem, the provider is not recognize at compilation and my build fail. I learn by searching that apparently, this error means my tag is misplaced. Well... If I move it it Android SMARTLY (yes this is ironic) regenerate it here without asking anything. And obvioulsy fail it's build.

Here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.matthieu.projet"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.example.matthieu.projet.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.matthieu.projet.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: All providers should be inside the application tag. You have one outside.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the wrong manifest file. Ignore the one that pops up in the IDE, as that is one that is generated as part of the build process and displayed erroneously, courtesy of [this three-year-old Android Studio bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37017432).

Go back into your module and edit the original manifest.

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html) for more.